# ROUGE Warning: test instance for peer 13 does not exist for evaluation 5

Tags: rouge

I use rouge to evaluate my summary result. the setting xml looks like this:

[image: evaluate setting xml]

The model files and system files are are all in the a folder 'models' and 'systems', like this:
[image]
[image]

After running  the rouge script, i get a lots of warning as:
[image]

Is there something wrong? can i ignore these warnings?

Comment: I suggest you to use Java implementation of Rouge. check your results with that. http://kavita-ganesan.com/content/rouge-2.0

Comment: I want to use the stemming, but it seem java implementation has no such a  option, any suggestion?@Mahmood Kohansal

Comment: Besides, it seem that there is no skip-ngram evaluation.